# Tikz lines being cut off from origin

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to use tikz for the first time. I have successfully created the diagram I wanted apart from there being two lines that don't start from their origin. Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (current bounding box.north)]
    \node (v1) at (0,0) {};
    \node (v2) at (2,0) {};
    \node (v3) at (4,0) {};
    \node (at1) at (3.2,0.2) {$\alpha$};
    \draw[dashed]  (v1) edge (v3);
    \draw[->,rotate=20] (v2) -- ++(2,0) node[right] {$\vec{i}$};
    \draw[->,rotate=20] (v2) -- ++(0,2) node[top] {$\vec{j}$};
    \draw[rotate=20] (v2) ++(0.3,0) -- ++(0,0.3);
    \draw[rotate=20] (v2) ++(0,0.3) -- ++(0.3,0);
    \draw ([shift=(0:1)]2,0) arc (0:20:1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Picture showing that lines are cut off]

Also, how do I align the j vector to be above the arrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `above` instead of `top`. Furthermore, I would suggest to use `\coordinate`s instead of empty `\node`s.

[image: position]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (current bounding box.north)]
    \coordinate (v1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (v2) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (v3) at (4,0);
    \node (at1) at (3.2,0.2) {$\alpha$};
    \draw[dashed]  (v1) edge (v3);
    \draw[->,rotate=20] (v2) -- ++(2,0) node[right] {$\vec{i}$};
    \draw[->,rotate=20] (v2) -- ++(0,2) node[above] {$\vec{j}$};
    \draw[rotate=20] (v2) ++(0.3,0) -- ++(0,0.3);
    \draw[rotate=20] (v2) ++(0,0.3) -- ++(0.3,0);
    \draw ([shift=(0:1)]2,0) arc (0:20:1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, I have it all working now. Thanks. I'll make sure to use coordinates instead of nodes when needed.